# Check a number in SQL Server and then generate a unique number in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to generate a unique number after checking duplication in SQL Server.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I doubt anyone can understand the problem here. Please reword your question

Comment: what value you want to update?

Comment: i need to update the Logged Out Time , i Just need to generate a Unique ID number after checking in the sqlserver , i can take care of the rest by my self. And my english is too bad very very sorry for that

Comment: You need to be more specific. Tell us what the problem is. We cannot write your code for you. What do you not know how to do? To query SQL Server? To compare numbers? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have 2 application

Comment: i am running 2 software , first is admin and the second is client side application , i need to know that which user is currently online, i have created some table  with the entity  BETTER | BETTERNAME | LOGINTIME | LOGOUTTIME | LOGINTIME  ..  i have created a method on the Login page`s LOGIN BUTTON when ever user will click it it will insert the BETTER ID , BETTER NAME , LOGINTIME , EVery thing is working fine till now .

Comment: The issue i am facing is when the user close the application , on the closing event i have a PROCEDURE update TABLE set LoggedOutTime = '@'loggedoutTime where BetterId = '@'BetterId and IsLoggedIn = 1 and id = '@'id , But this query will update all the entries of the current user not just one

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with this. Here is one example:

In your SQL table, create an ID field and define it as `auto increment`. When a new user is inserted, you do not set a value for this field -- SQL Server will automatically give it a value larger than any of the existing values.

It is unclear to me if you don't know how to insert into the database. If so, this is too general a topic to answer here. You should Google some C# tutorials.

Comment: thanks, on the runtime is there anyway to determine that generated id number before using the update command? the update query will be like this update table set column = value where id = "that generated number"

Comment: It would not be safe to try to deduce what the ID will be. The correct thing to do is to query the DB after the user logs in and the ID is assigned. If this is not good enough, then don't use auto increment. Instead, say, create your own ID field, and SELECT MAX(ID) before inserting the user. Then add 1 to the MAX(ID) and insert. But then you might have all sorts of problems if multiple users are logging in at the same time from different locations.